# peoplesoft oprid as a field in a query

Tags: expression, userid, peoplesoft

Is there a way to add the `oprid` of the person who runs the query into the query result?

Example: If my `oprid` is `hr01` and I try running a specific query with a prompt that limits the result to 1 row - `Performance Ratings of Employee XXXXX as of XX-XX-XXXX`, a 1 row result would come up (or exported as excel) with my `oprid` appearing as the last column. If somebody else runs this report, the the `oprid` appearing in the last column should be that user's `oprid`.

I know that we usually get the `oprid` from `PSOPRDEFN` or `PSQRYEXECLOG` or even `EMPLMT_SRCH_GBL`, but how do you make this join with the existing query?

Can someone please point me to a direction?
Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an expression, and give it the value `%operatorid`

Then add this expression as a field to you query and you are done.

If you need to concatenane it to some constants or others field , you'll have to encapsulate it between ()

Example :

```
'Performance Ratings of Employee XXXXX by '||(%operatorid)
```